# SSIS - variable driven package

Tags: ssis

I have a package that is essentially trying to copy 26 tables from oracle to sql server. 
Its not a complete table copy, we are looking for records that belong to certain 'Regions' of our company.

I pull the data from oracle 
I started just doing this with elbow grease, but each of the 26 tables required several variable to do the deletes, the fetches etc.

Long story short, I decided to use variables to represent the table names (source, temp and target).

This allowed me to copy/paste one sequence and effectively bypass a lot of click click in bids.

The problem I am running into is that the meta data seems to be very fragile. Sequences all seem to run on their owwn, but when i run the whole package, it breaks. And never in the same place.

Is this approach just a bad idea w/ SSIS?

Comment: I think that you need to double check how your variables are being initialised. If things run on their own but the whole package breaks, it sounds like your variable values are being modified by one sequence to something unexpected. Then the next sequence might fail.

Comment: Beyond @DeanOC's fine theory, mine is that the metadata in one flow might be dependent upon a previous task. Seems somewhat suspicious but depending on how much much sand got mixed in with the elbow grease. I find that I have a better SSIS experience if I keep my packages tightly focused on one subject area and then coordinate the whole process with a master package.

Comment: @billinkc is right, also sometimes there could be allowed some number of connections to to Oracle..., if you using in dataflow 3 or more source tables, you can break that limit...

Comment: the 26 sequence boxes are connected in serial. The first step in each is to set the variables. (actually, it works out that i can set 1 , and everything else builds off that.


I gave up on the approach. The whole concept was devised to save development time, clearly, it failed. LOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to take this off the board....

Each sequence container had the following ops

Script task - set variables
Execute SQL task   - delete from temp
data flow SourceToTemp -
       ole db source  - used a generic select * from tbl to temp_tbl
       derived column1  - insert a timestamp column
       oledb destination - map all the columns into a temp table  (****THIS IS THE BIG PROBLEM CHILD)
Execute SQL task   - delete from target
Execute SQL task  - insert target select from temp

the oleDB destination is the piece that kept breaking.

Since it references variables, I had to be very careful at design time to set the variables correctly before opening one of the data flows.

I am pretty sure this is the problem. Since I can not say w/ certainty when SSIS refreshes meta data in the design environment, I cant be sure if/when sequence X refreshed while the variables were set to support sequence Y.

So while it conceptually should work at run time, dev time is a change control night mare.

I have changed all the oleDB destinations to point to a hard table name. this is really a small concession since there are 4 sql statements that are still driven by variables. (saving me a lot of clicking and typing)

This small change has eliminated the 'shifting sands' problem.

Take-a-way lesson : dont have an oledb destination be basesd on a variable.

thanks for the comments